# Merge 2 request SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a problem when i want merge 2 SQL queries.

> Indeed i've an error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

I don't undestand why i've this message because i've 1 row after "IN".

1 - Query SUB CATEGORY EMPTY (sub category have not any blog post):

```
 SELECT category.id, category.name, category.parent, article.id 
 FROM category 
 INNER JOIN article 
 WHERE (article.category != category.id AND category.parent IS NOT NULL) 
 GROUP BY category.id
```

2 - Query All categories without any sub-category

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM category 
   WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT parent 
                     FROM category 
                     WHERE parent IS NOT NULL) 
   AND parent IS NULL
```

3 - Merged queries:

```
SELECT category.id, category.name, category.parent, article.id 
FROM category 
INNER JOIN article 
WHERE (article.category != category.id 
AND category.parent IS NOT NULL) OR (SELECT * 
                                      FROM category 
                                      WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT parent 
        FROM category 
        WHERE parent IS NOT NULL) AND parent IS NULL) 
GROUP BY category.id
```

I've try with comas but it's doesn't works too.

With this merged query i must have a list of category without subcategory + subcategory without blog post.

[SQL diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohM0q.png)

Thank you for your helping, Cyril.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  `MERGE` actually means something in many databases -- and it has nothing to do with combining two `SELECT`s in some fashion.  And why doesn't your `JOIN` have an `ON` or `USING` clause?

Comment: I think the error is in the `OR`  operand. `OR (SELECT * FROM category  WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT parent  FROM category  WHERE parent IS NOT NULL)` You are selecting all the data, you must use only one column in `OR` condition

Comment: What you call *merge* is actually *union* in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try

```
---
--- 1 - Query "SUB CATEGORY EMPTY" (sub category have not any blog post):
---
select
    category.id, 
    category.name, 
    category.parent, 
    article.id 
from 
    category left join article 
     on (category.id = article.category)
where
    article.id is null
    and category.parent is not null
group by
    category.id, 
    category.name, 
    category.parent, 
    article.id 
    
---
--- 2 - Query "All categories without any sub-category"
---
select
    category.id, 
    category.name, 
    category.parent, 
    null as article_id
from
    category
where
    category.id not in (select parent from category where parent is not null group by parent )
    and category.parent is null

---
--- 3 - Merged queries:
---
select
    category.id, 
    category.name, 
    category.parent, 
    article.id 
from 
    category left join article 
     on (category.id = article.category)
where
    article.id is null
    and category.parent is not null
group by
    category.id, 
    category.name, 
    category.parent, 
    article.id 
union all
select
    category.id, 
    category.name, 
    category.parent, 
    null as article_id
from
    category
where
    category.id not in (select parent from category where parent is not null group by parent )
    and category.parent is null
```

Comment: Thank you ! I tried with the 3rd request but I have a problem (article.id does not exist). (BUT) so i checked your query and saw "UNION ALL" so i did this (and it works):

`SELECT 
    category.id, category.name, category.parent, article.id 
FROM 
    category 
INNER JOIN 
    article
WHERE 
    article.category != category.id 
AND 
    category.parent IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY category.id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM category
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT parent
    FROM category 
    WHERE parent IS NOT NULL
)
AND 
parent IS NULL
GROUP BY category.id`

Comment: ok, glad I was able to help you :-)